# computed observable not updating based on check box values

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

Hope you are doing great.

I'm currently working on UI interface with KnockoutJS and i want to accomplish the following:

In my UI, i obtain a **list of components from a JSON file**, (some checkboxes based on bool values, some number input based on int values, etc.). Some components are dependent of others like :

- Enable custom rate ( A checkbox)

  - Custom rate ( Number input)

The **custom rate parameter** in the JSON file has a field called **dependencies** in which we define a condition string ("parent1 && parent2").

My idea is to **build a isVisible computed observable** using the parameters observable array value.

```
viewModel.isVisible = ko.computed(function(){
        var expr = "Han && Solo";
    var parentVars = expr.split(' && ');
    var result = ko.observable(true);
    for(var i = 0; i < parentVars.length; i++){
            let element = viewModel.getParamByName(parentVars[i],viewModel.paramsArray());
        if(element != 'not found'){
          result = result && element.isVisible();
        }
    }

    return result;

});
```

I try to implement this idea here: https://jsfiddle.net/bignacio/y32g4801/62/

But the computed result is not binding.

How to fix this issue? is there a better approach to handle the problem?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed observable should not return an observable. It should just return a value. Therefore, the fourth line should be:

```
var result = true;
```

The computed observable is checking the `isVisible` property of each matching item, but those items are not bound correctly to the checkboxes. Instead of using the `value` binding, you should be using the `checked` binding:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $data.isVisible">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y32g4801/78/